# How can i return bootstrap modal as partial view on button click?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to show a modal popup when user clicks on a button and i want to render the modal from controller.
_BookNow.cshtml

```
@model Booking

 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Hello Lets Book Now</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <form asp-action="BookNow" asp-controller="Booking" method="POST">
           .......
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

My Controller Action

```
      [HttpGet]
     public async Task<IActionResult> BookNow(int vId)
    {
        ViewBag.venueId = vId;
        return PartialView("_BookNow");
    }
```

I want to get the modal appear in details page when use clicks BookNow button
Details.cshtml

```
<a asp-controller="Booking" asp-action="BookNow" asp-route-vId="@Model.Venue.Id">
                    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-book"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> 
                     @(Model.IsBooked? "Booked" : "Book Now")
                    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponent`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

You can try this:

Views/Booking/Components/BookNow/**BookNowViewComponent.cs**

```
    public class BookNowViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int vId)
        {
            ViewBag.venueId = vId;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Views/Booking/Components/BookNow/**Default.cshtml**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Hello Lets Book Now</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form asp-action="BookNow" asp-controller="Booking" method="POST">
                    .......
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Details.cshtml

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Book Now</button>

@await Component.InvokeAsync("BookNow", new { vId = Model.Venue.Id })
```

Comment: Thanks ma that helped me, but is there any other way to load  modal from server in my details view only after the booknow button is clicked?.

Comment: Glad it helped. 
You can do it via ajax get on button click, and call .modal('show')